# Recursion on matrices in R

Tags: r, recursion, matrix

I have 3 matrices, all of then of the same order, A_0, A_1 and A_2.
I need to calculate recursively some matrix R according to this algorithm:
Initialize R_0 = matrix of zeroes.
Then, R_(k + 1) =( R_k * R_k *A_2 + A_0 ) * Inverse(A_1)

The matrices A_0, A_1 and A_2 are all defined, with same dimensions M * M.

This is what I tried:

```
library(matlib)
R.0<- matrix(0, M, M)
for (i in 1:50){
      R.i<-(R.(i-1)%*%R.(i-1)%*%A.2+A.0)%*%inv(A.1)
      }
```

and I get the following:
"Error in R.(i - 1) : could not find function "R."

I want the last matrix, i.e. R_50.

Thanks,

Nir.

Comment: Try with `R.0 <- (R.0%*%R.0%*%A.2+A.0)%*%inv(A.1)`. At the end of the loop R.0 should contain your desired result